# How to get xls cell position in PHP

Tags: php, foreach

I am trying to import data from xls file,And for this i am using "spreadsheet library" and i am getting data successfully in following format (array)

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [0] => ABC
            [1] => XYZ
            ...
         )
[1] => Array
        (
            [1] => ADW
        )
...
```

Now i want to save "Cell" value into database,For example in "xls" file, "ABC" position is "A1" And "XYZ" is "B1",So "ADW" position is "A2",So how can i get "Cell Position" using Php ?

Comment: don't spam with irrelevant tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could compute cell position from the indexes of the array, with rows starting at 1 at index 0 and columns starting at `A` at index 0:

```php
$data = array (
    0 => 
    array (
        0 => 'ABC',
        1 => 'XYZ'
    ),
    1 => 
    array (
        1 => 'ADW',
        20 => 'XYZ',
        26 => 'AA2',
        30 => 'PQR',
        60 => 'WWW',
        701 => 'ZZZ'
    )
);

$result = array();

foreach ($data as $rownum => $row) {
    foreach ($row as $colnum => $value) {
        if ($colnum >= 26) {
            $col0 = $colnum % 26;
            $col1 = intdiv($colnum, 26);
            $colstr = chr(64 + $col1) . chr(65 + $col0);
        }
        else {
            $colstr = chr(65+$colnum);
        }
        $result[$colstr . ($rownum+1)] = $value;
    }
}

print_r($result);
```

Output (for my sample data):

```
Array
(
    [A1] => ABC
    [B1] => XYZ
    [B2] => ADW
    [U2] => XYZ
    [AA2] => AA2
    [AE2] => PQR
    [BI2] => WWW
    [ZZ2] => ZZZ
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/s2Pom)

Comment: its working at "Z" column, but after "z" columns its not working because after that XLS working as "AA" "AB" "AC"... like that , How can i do this

Comment: @Rick sorry about that, I didn't consider that possibility. My edited code will work up to `ZZ`

Comment: sorry but its not working , giving wrong data , for example, instead of "AA" its giving "AB1" as result

Comment: after "z" should work as "AA" "AB" "AC" and so on...

Comment: @Rick I did have a problem with `AA`,  the test against 26 should have been `>=`, not `>`. So now for column 26 it gives `AA`, then `AB` etc. Please see my edit.

Comment: its working but my last question is how to print those values who is not empty ? ( i have some empty values)

Comment: @Rick do you mean empty as in `''`? See https://3v4l.org/sTILq

Comment: i want to remove empty array values , Hope you understand

Comment: @Rick see the demo, those empty results are not in the output